# Help identifying tropical[?] plant

Tags: identification

I have a policy of letting unknown plants in my garden grow until I can identify them --- it makes it easier to know weeds when they're young if I can see what they grow into. The following has me stumped; details:

- It's grown into a 6' behemoth with extremely fuzzy/furry leaves and stem/trunk
- It sprouted tiny purple flowers last week
- It is maybe nine months old, but most of the growth has taken place in the last month or so
- I live near downtown Los Angeles

Based on its general structure I'm guessing it's some sort of tropical, but I have no solid knowledge one way or the other.

[image: Plant profile; approximately 6 feet tall with large leaves; entire plant is fuzzy]
[image: My hands are on the small side of average for a guy; these leaves are huge]
[image: Tiny purple inflorescence; this is the only one on the plant, at the top; apologies for focus issues]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [Solanum mauritianum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_mauritianum), commonly known as Bugweed. Its a nightshade, and as such, all parts of the plant are poisonous if ingested.

Comment: Thanks --- seems like a bad dude and might explain some rashes I've been getting in the yard lately. (there are reports of irritation from simply being near one of these)

Comment: added a link to provide more info